# run jpm with profile: how to see console messages?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

When I run my extension with

```
jpm -p myuser
```

I don't see any console.log messages any more: that's almsot impossible to debug.

Same trouble described here : https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/jpm-run-with-profile-and-logging/3114/3

Any idea how to solve that ?

Comment: 1. Try answer by @canuckistani. 2. Alternatively try `console.error()`. 3. And finally: remember that you won't see no console logs coming from content scripts. To access logs of content scripts use `Browser Console` (`ctrl+shift+j`), and sieve by some string, which you'll be adding to your every log for their identification.

Answer (score 4):

You might need to add a preference to the profile you're using to see all addon log messages, [see this blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2013/03/27/changes-to-console-log-behaviour-in-sdk-1-14/) for the gory details. IMO this is a jpm bug, when it copies the profile it's using it should set this preferences.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is [better to include the essential parts of the answer here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline